# How to update a complex array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this structure in state

```
allVotes: [
  {
    id: "vote_1",
    title: "How is your day?",
    description: "Tell me: how has your day been so far?",
    choices: [
      { id: "choice_1", title: "Good", count: 7 },
      { id: "choice_2", title: "Bad", count: 12 },
      { id: "choice_3", title: "Not sure yet", count: 1 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "vote_2",
    title: "Programming languages",
    description: "What is your preferred language?",
    choices: [
      { id: "choice_1", title: "JavaScript", count: 5 },
      { id: "choice_2", title: "Java", count: 9 },
      { id: "choice_3", title: "Plain english", count: 17 },
    ],
  },
],
```

and need to update count. This works (in a Controller Component)

```
registerVote(vote, choice) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      allVotes: prevState.allVotes.map(
        pVote =>
          pVote.id !== vote.id
            ? pVote
            : {
                ...pVote,
                choices: pVote.choices.map(
                  pChoice =>
                    pChoice.id !== choice.id
                      ? pChoice
                      : {
                          ...pChoice,
                          count: pChoice.count + 1,
                        },
                ),
              },
      ),
    };
  });
}
```

but it looks very complicated and I am not quite sure
if this is the right way. Is there better way?

Comment: You might want to use [`immutable`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) which is also made by Facebook that plays nicely with React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decomposite your component into smaller ones. Say: Form, Votes, Vote.

```
class Vote extends React.Component {
    increment = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            count: prevState.count + 1
        }), this.onItemChange);
    }

    onItemChange = () => {
        this.props.onItemChange(this.state, this.props.id);
    }
}


class Votes extends React.Component {
    onItemChangedCallback = (itemToUpdate, idToUpdate) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            allVotes: prevState.allVotes.map(vote => vote.id === idToUpdate? {...itemToUpdate}: vote; )
        }), this.onVotesChangeCallback);
    }

    onVotesChangeCallback = () => {
        this.props.onVotesChange(this.state.allVotes)
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>this.state.allVotes.map(vote => <Vote id={vote.id} key={vote.id} vote={vote} onItemChange={this.onItemChangedCallback} />)</div>);
    }
}
```

Besides it means more classes/components this fits "single responsibility" principle: so `Votes` handles moving elements inside the list, deletion and adding new but not timestamp value, voters' amount or voters list. `Vote` handles single item. And so on. Better to test, easier to read, easier to reuse in different context.

[UPD] after more thinking on that I believe that it's better passing unique id from Votes to Vote rather than positional index(as well as `key` props suggests). And later use it id to figure out what collection's element should be replaced. Updated code snippet accordingly.

[UPD2] I guess `Vote` can be functional/stateless component but I better keep it class-based to keep idea easier to follow

Answer (score 2):

Thats actually the way to do if you want to keep immutability, however you could simplify it a bit by using some helper functions:

```
 const change = (key, fn) => obj => ({ ...obj, [key]: fn(obj[key]) });
 const changeOne = (filter, fn) => arr => arr.map(el => filter(el) ? fn(el) : el);

 this.setState(change("allVotes", changeOne(v => v.id === vote.id, change("count", c => c + 1))));
```

Comment: thank you! (I am react beginner, impressive to see this ... ;))